# Selecting button within angular table which contains multiple buttons made up of the same ID

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

I am trying to write a selenium test in C# for the scenario below.

I need to be able to click the undo button on certain records in the table below based on their transfer type.

[image: Table]

However the undo button is made up of the following HTML

```
<a href="" style="vertical-align: middle" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-show="true" ng-click="executeUndoCommand(transfer)">Undo</a>
```

I am able to select mulitple undo buttons but I wish to be able to select a specific undo button depending on transfer type.

I am able to select the row within the table I wish to click undo for but I am unable to get a locator on a specific button. I cannot locate the button via its position on screen either as any new records are added to the top of the table quite frequently

The HTML for the entire first row is as follows

```
<tr ng-repeat="transfer in completedTransfersSummary track by $id(transfer)">
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle" ng- 
    style="transfer.isDisabled &amp;&amp; {color:'#A6A6A6'}" ng-class=" 
   {'highlight' : transfer.transferorBusinessId == CisBusinessID }" 
    class="highlight">608445</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle" ng- 
    style="transfer.isDisabled &amp;&amp; {color:'#A6A6A6'}" ng-class=" 
   {'highlight' : transfer.transfereeBusinessId == CisBusinessID 
}">608446</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle" nowrap="" ng- 
    style="transfer.isDisabled &amp;&amp; {color:'#A6A6A6'}">Sale or 
Gift</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle" nowrap="" ng- 
   style="transfer.isDisabled &amp;&amp; {color:'#A6A6A6'}">05/07/2018</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle" nowrap="" ng- 
   style="transfer.isDisabled &amp;&amp; {color:'#A6A6A6'}">15/05/2017</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle" nowrap="" ng- 
   style="transfer.isDisabled &amp;&amp; {color:'#A6A6A6'}">1.00 entitlements @ 
    €229.27</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle" ng- 
   style="transfer.isDisabled &amp;&amp; {color:'#A6A6A6'}">526461</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle" ng- 
   style="transfer.isDisabled &amp;&amp; {color:'#A6A6A6'}">2017</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle" ng- 
   style="transfer.isDisabled &amp;&amp; {color:'#A6A6A6'}"></td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle;" ng- 
   show="undoWithdrawRoleAssignedToUser">
                            <div ng-show="transfer.transferorBusinessId == 
    CisBusinessID">
                                <a href="" style="vertical-align: middle" 
    class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-show="true" ng- 
     click="executeUndoCommand(transfer)">Undo</a>
                                <a href="" style="vertical-align: middle" 

class="btn btn-primary btn-sm ng-hide" ng-show="false" ng- 
 click="showUndoModal(transfer)">Undo</a>

                                    <a href="" style="vertical-align: middle" 
class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-show="true" ng- 
click="executeWithdrawCommand(transfer)">Withdraw</a>
                                    <a href="" style="vertical-align: middle" 
class="btn btn-default btn-sm ng-hide" ng-show="false" ng- 
click="showWithdrawModal(transfer)">Withdraw</a>

                                    <label style="vertical-align: middle" ng- 
show="false" ng-style="transfer.isDisabled &amp;&amp; {color:'#A6A6A6'}" 
class="ng-hide"></label>
                                    <label style="vertical-align: middle" ng- 
show="false" ng-style="transfer.isDisabled &amp;&amp; {color:'#A6A6A6'}" 
class="ng-hide"></label>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below XPath to match Undo button by TransferType value:

```
//tr[td="Sale or Gift"]//a[@ng-click="executeUndoCommand(transfer)"]
```

Just replace `td="Sale or Gift"` with `td="Lease"`, `td="Merger"`...

Answer (score 1):

You can try next:

```
private By allRowElement = By.xpath("//xpath_for_all_table_row");
private By transferType = By.xpath(".//xpath_for_transfer_type");// here "." on start is very important
private By undoButton = By.xpath(".//xpath_for_undo_button"); // here "." on start is very important

public void clickUndoBtn(String transferTypeValue) {
    List<WebElement> tempList = driver.findElements(allRowElement);
    for (WebElement row : tempList) {
        if (transferTypeValue.equals(row.findElement(transferType).getText())) {
            row.findElement(undoButton).click();
        }
    }
}

//return List of elements depends on transfer type value
public List<WebElement> getElements(String transferTypeValue) {
    List<WebElement> tempList = driver.findElements(allRowElement);
    return tempList.stream()
            .filter(row -> transferTypeValue.equals(row.findElement(transferType).getText())).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Notice: **WebElement** object have possibility to search elements. And if xpath starts with "." WebElement object will search for element inside himself(children elements)

Answer (score 1):

As per your question and the *HTML* you have provided you may require to invoke `click()` on multiple elements with text as **Undo** with respect to the texts in *Transfer Type* column e.g. **Sale or Gift**, **Lease** or **Merger**. So you can write a function as follows:

```
public void clickUndo(string transferType)
{
    driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//td[text()='" + state + "']//following::div[1]//a[@class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' and @ng-show='true']")).Click();
}
```

Now you can call the function `clickUndo()` with any of the *Transfer Type* as follows:

```
clickUndo("Sale or Gift")
clickUndo("Lease")
clickUndo("Merger")
```

**Note** : As you mentioned this to be an [**Angular**](https://angular.io/) table, you have to induce *WebDriverWait* before you invoke the `click()`.